# Python package to manipulate linear systems

Tags: python, control-systems

I'm doing some control system work.  I was shocked* -- *shocked* to learn that while Scipy has some nice linear systems classes, they don't extend to computing the cascades or paralleling of two systems.

I.e., in Scilab if you have system `H` and system `G`, you can express their parallel as `HpG = H + G`, or their cascade as `HcG = H * G` -- in other words, just do the intuitive thing as if you were manipulating transfer functions.

Is there a commonly-used Python package that offers this convenience?

* After years of using Python for signal processing -- it's been a while since I've done serious control systems work.

Comment: Yes, this arguably belongs in stackoverflow.  I felt my hit rate with people who use Python and could answer the question "what is a transfer function" would be much higher here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Control System Library in Python handles all this quite well, and maps closely to the MATLAB Control Toolbox in functionality.

https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.3.post2/

Demo:

```
import control as con
H = con.tf([1, 0], [1, -1, 1])
G = con.tf([1, 1], [1, -1])

print(H)
print(G)

     s
-----------
s^2 - s + 1


s + 1
-----
s - 1

print(H+G)

  s^3 + s^2 - s + 1
---------------------
s^3 - 2 s^2 + 2 s - 1


print(H*G)

       s^2 + s
---------------------
s^3 - 2 s^2 + 2 s - 1
```

Hint: be sure to use the `control.minreal()` function liberally when combining transfer functions (eliminates matching pole/zero pairs that wouldn't necessarily be automatically factored out). I typically wrap any operation that involves manipulating transfer functions with `control.minreal()` to keep orders as small as possible before then being combined / expanded with other higher levels, unless I am sure there are no common factors (such as in the example given above).